# Always append new text to current text in column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to have a "notes" item in a model that always appends any new text from the form on new/edit to any currently existing notes.

I'm looking at something like:

```
 def update
     ppe_params[:notes] = @ppe.notes + "/n" + ppe_params[:notes]
     respond_to do |format|
       if @ppe.update(ppe_params)
         format.html { gflash :success => 'PPE was successfully updated.'; redirect_to @ppe }
       else
         format.html { render :edit }
       end
     end
```

end

This seems like a simple solution, so what are the pitfalls? I'm using Postgres and not too worried about running out of room with the TEXT column in Postgres. Is it better form to move this to a method in the model?

Is there a way to cause Postgres to always append the new note text to the current column value?

Comment: (1) Don't you mean `"\n"` rather than `"/n"`? (2) Why not `has_many :notes` and create a new note every time? You'd be able to mash them all together for display purposes but you'd have individual notes with timestamps/authors/...

Comment: @muistooshort heck even an array or json column is a better idea... And I usually get my pitchfork at the slightest sign of denormalization.

Comment: Both excellent points. This would mean migrating current note data to a new table but worth the effort. Tracking date and who made the note is something we'd like and that gives us all of it in one fell swoop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would not use this method in general. You COULD use a trigger on update to simply append the new value instead of overwriting.
The problem with this would be that there would be absolutely no way to clear out the column without disabling or bypassing triggers which would be ultra annoying.

If you have to have this functionality, I'd just put it in the application level and not resort to implementing this in the database. I'll write the DB code if you request, but it's such a bad idea (from my thinking) that I don't want someone implementing that code without thinking about the ramifications.

Comment: This is more of a comment then an actual answer.

Comment: I agree. I think the comment is more valuable than an answer to the actual question, however, the alternative (separate table) mentioned is a viable solution that would work well.

Answer (score 1):

As @muistooshort pointed out this really deserves to be it's own table with `:comment`, `:date`, and `:user_id` in the table, and `has_many`/`belongs_to` in the appropriate models. That is the route I will take. Thanks all for the reality check, sometimes having my head in too many place I forget good DB design.